# Why is my code sending the prompts to my phone, but not to anyone else who attempts to send a message to the bot?

Tags: javascript, twilio

When I send a message to the Twilio phone number from my phone, it displays the questions that I want the user to see. However, if someone else sends a message no prompts are shown to the user. This is stored in a database. At first, I thought it was because the number sending a message was not getting stored as phoneNumber, but after checking in the database it is stored as phoneNumber.

I already tried adding a Status Callback function to the code but it doesn't say anything about the status of the message.

```
if(body === 'x'){ //checks body to have a key phrase, it it does it creates the message
    let newMessage = new Message();
    newMessage.phoneNumber = from;
    newMessage.save(() => {
        client.messages.create({ //sends message to the patient
            to: `${from}`,
            from: `${to}`,
            body: 'What is your full name?' 
        })
        .then(message => console.log(message.sid));

        res.end();
    })
}
```

The expected output would be the prompt of full name if someone sends a message to the Twilio number. However, it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can think of a couple of reasons that might be affecting you here.

First up, if you are still using a trial account then you can only send SMS messages to numbers that you have verified with your account. There are [instructions for how to verify numbers with your Twilio account here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio). You can remove this restriction by upgrading your account.

Secondly, depending on the platform you are using, there may be a race condition between sending the message and the response ending. You call `client.messages.create` and handle the promise when it resolves, but your code goes straight on to end the response synchronously. It is the case with [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) and it may be on other platforms, that ending the response ends all processing and that might result in the request to send a message getting cancelled. You say you are getting messages when you try from your phone, so this may not be the issue, I just thought I'd share in case.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: The first suggestion fixed the issue. Thank you!